# creating DefaultHttpClient causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to use the Apache DefaultHttpClient to execute a JSON POST request and it's giving me  a NoClassDefFound Error when i try to instantiate it.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

I've included the following jars in my buildpath,

httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2-alpha2.jar
json-simple-1.1.1.jar
fluent-hc-4.2.5.jar
httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar
httpmime-4.2.5.jar
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.2.5.jar

I have no problem when I try to import DefaultHttpClient as follows

```
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

but only when I try and make an instance of it as mentioned above.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:187)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146)
    at AtlasService.main(AtlasService.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: I just solved the issue so I'm just answering to help future souls. I was using http-core 4.2-alpha jar and was using 4.2.5 for the rest(http-client, http-client-cache, http-mime etc.). The problem went away after I updated the http-core-4.2-alpha jar to http-core-4.2.5. You can find the jar in the maven repos online.

Comment: My problem was that I was using a version of the libs for Android in a Java project, I needed to download the normal java versions to get rid of the problem.